# How to resize an std::vector without loosing the existing data?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I was implementing an algorithm that needs me to remove and add the same elements from a vector each iteration of a loop.

Example:

iteration 1 : |1 2 3 4| (size 4)

iteration 2 : |1 3| 2 4 (size 2 with the elements '2' and '4' still there in memory but not accounted for in the size of the vector)

iteration 3 : |1 2 3| 4 (size 3 with the element '4' still there)

Basically, I want to be able to change the value returned by the size() function without affecting the vector for performance reasons.

I know I could use another variable outside of my vector to keep track of its size, but I wanted to know if it could be possible directly internally in the std::vector container.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Change your design: Instead of containers and size, talk about *iterators*. You can then shuffle, permute and partition your data in any way you desire, but you give *iterators* to the interesting ranges out to your algorithm.

Comment: When you "shrink" a vector using erase the capacity does not change.  That is what determines when a vector needs to reallocate.

Comment: @NathanOliver Nothing here about capacity nor reallocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that.

The only way to reduce the value reported  by `size()` is to resize.  When resizing reduces the size, the elements outside the new size no longer exist as far as the program is concerned.   Any means of accessing them (or reaccessing them, in your case) yields undefined behaviour.

If you want to track the number of elements of an array in use (say, that you are using two elements of a vector with five elements) then create an extra variable to keep track of that.   To state the (hopefully) obvious, that variable will need to be kept consistent with the size of the vector (e.g. to avoid tracking that ten elements are being used in a vector with five elements).

If you want to keep the variable with the vector, make both members of a `struct`/`class` type.  That class can provide member functions or operations that manage both the vector and the number of elements "in use", to ensure consistency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, well I guess I'll have to track the size on my own

Answer (score 8):

What you want is logically inconsistent with how `vector` works. `size` returns the number of objects of type `T` in the `vector`. By reducing that size, any objects chopped off the end are destroyed. When you increase the size, you are adding *new objects*.

It would be better to build a type *around* `vector` that has the behavior you want.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, maybe use `has-a` instead of `is-a`?

```
template <typename T> class subvector {
protected:
  std::vector<T> owner_;
  std::size_t    begin_;
  std::size_t    end_;
public:
  subvector(std::vector<T>& owner, size_t from, size_t to) :
    owner_(owner), begin_(from), end_(to)
  {
     // do some range checks
  }

  size_t size() const {
    // range check before return
    // either throw (fast-fail) *or* 
    //   adjust the out-of-range ends (lenient but maybe unsafe)
    return end_-begin_+1;
  }
  // implement as many of the std::vector methods/operators
  // you are likely to need in your code by delegation
  // to the owner_.
  // Stay minimal, whenever you use something you don't have, 
  // the compiler will tell you.
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I clearly understood your code snippet, but I couldn't understand what you mean by "use has-a instead of is-a". Could you clarify ?

Comment: @CpCd0y Its a description of inheritance in polymorphism, if you publicly inherit, you are making something an `is-a`, where as if you use something, you are making a class that `has-a`. If i am right, this terminology likely came from "Effective C++" the book.

Comment: @CpCd0y `is-a` derived by inheritance - uses method override for customisation of behaviour.
`has-a` derived by composition - wrap around an object, delegate all the behaviour to the wrapped object, customize those you want before delegation.

Comment: @Ben - for reference,  "Effective C++" _may_ be a good starting point for someone unaware. Personally, I haven't read it (this is why the "_may_") but those are patterns quite common in OOP world, regardless of the language

Comment: "Is-a" and "has-a" are not OO patterns. They are descriptions of relationships between entities (which, depending on context, may be objects, classes, etc). An "is-a" relationship describes a particular relationship involving specialisation of types (e.g. a Labrador is a Dog).  Ownership and composition are both types of "has-a" relationship (e.g. a Person has a Home, or a Person has a Leg). In C++ "is-a" is often implemented using public inheritance and "has-a" relationships may be implemented in various ways (private inheritance, containment/membership, containing a pointer, etc, etc).

Comment: @Peter sudden attack of pedantry? ;) I can do it too, you know? E.g. _show me where I did I say <"Is-a" and "has-a" are OO patterns>"_

Comment: Your comments were imprecise enough to be misleading.

Comment: @Peter - there, a well deserved +1 to your comment from me.