# Implementing Battlefield 3's std::vector swap trick to "remove/add" an element

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector

I'm trying to implement an algorithm and I stumbled upon DICE's "swap trick" as described [here](http://www.frostbite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CullingTheBattlefield.pdf) (slide 19).

From what I understand, we first create a vector with all of our elements and then when an element needs to be deleted, it is swapped with the last one and we decrease the "size" of the vector. This "size" is an external variable to keep track of our "virtual" size (because a vector [doesn't support this internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175949/how-to-resize-an-stdvector-without-loosing-the-existing-data)).

NOTE: ordering/sorting is not important. Also, when I say "delete", nothing is de-allocated, it's just saying that the element is moved outside of the "usable" range.

Now, when the moment comes to add an element (from the deleted ones) back in the usable part of the vector, we need to swap it back somewhere. And this is where I'm blocking a bit. Because, when we swap it, we could be swapping it with an element that needs to be there at this iteration and this same element would need to be swapped back and so on...

This is an example how it should work :

iteration 1 : |1 2 3 4| (size 4)

iteration 2 : |1 3| 2 4 (size 2 with the elements '2' and '4' still there in memory but not accounted for in the size of the vector)

iteration 3 : |2 1 3| 4 (size 3 with the element '4' still there)

I might be over-thinking it, but if anyone has an idea of how to get this algorithm right, that would be helpful.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If it's possible, you don't have to even swap elements but just overwrite deleted one by last one and erase that last element (so you don't have to keep tracking about valid elements).

Comment: "*I'm trying to implement an algorithm and I stumbled upon DICE's "swap trick" as described here (slide 19).*" What algorithm are you trying to implement here? The DICE "swap trick" is not about *erasing* elements from the list. It simply partitions the list into "visible" and "non-visible". The data in the non-visible range is just as valid as the visible data; it's simply not *visible*. So when it comes time to render, you render a contiguous range of visible entries. By contrast, you keep talking about "deleted" elements, which suggests that their data is no longer valid.

Comment: That's why I put quotes :)
I thought I was clear. I will try to correct that

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39175949?

Comment: Nope, look at both answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swap it with the first unusable element, then increment your virtual size. So, for example, let's say this is your vector:

```
  // usable         unusable
{ 0, 1, 2, 3,       4, 5, 6, 7, 8 } // virtual size = 4
```

Now let's say you want to move the 7 from the unusable portion to the usable portion. You swap it with the 4, since that's the first unusable element. And then you increment your virtual size by 1. So now your vector looks like this:

```
  // usable         // unusable
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 7,    5, 6, 4, 8 } // virtual size = 5
```

Comment: It was that simple, why didn't I see that. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I don't entirely see the benefit over a normal, reserved `std::vector<int>`, unless the requirement is that the "unusable" values aren't known and must be stored even while they're unused.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That seems to be precisely the requirement (assuming you mean "aren't unknown", instead of "aren't known").

Comment: @KerrebSB: Yep, that's it, I don't know which elements are going to be "unusable" even though I could predict that to a certain extent. And I can't just re-allocate all elements on the fly because it's too heavy.

Comment: @CpCd0y: I'd still say that this problem is best expressed as manipulating a triple of iterators in the fashion of std::rotate or std::partition...

Comment: @KerrekSB: I guess it would work better with std::partition. std::rotate would not be useful in this case, because it would work only in one particular case (i.e. the extremities), because the adding/removing of elements is very random.

Comment: @CpCd0y: No, I didn't mean to use either of those two particular algorithms, but rather used them as examples on how to work with triples of iterators, begin, middle, end.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I see. Thanks for the idea anyway (didn't know about std::partition in fact), I just reimplemented the algorithm using it (really straightforward and works perfectly)

Comment: @KerrebSB: the benefit of the "swap trick" is the O(1) removal complexity, wherease the original std::vector remove has O(n)